# Massive uptick in suspicious sessions/httpd processes

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

Apologies for the vague-ness, I understand this is quite difficult to diagnose.

Since yesterday, one of our client's sites has been experiencing a huge uptick in `httpd` processes, eating well over 100% of CPU. Google analytics seems to corroborate this, as there's been a ton of sessions out of nowhere. Their location is all `(not set)`, and have a 100% bounce rate.

I don't want to be dramatic enough to call it a DDoS, but it certainly seems to be something nasty. Seeing they're all from different IPs and don't appear to follow any pattern I can see, are there any steps I can take to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Put a reverse proxy with caching, eg. Varnish, in front of your Apache server.